# wpf datagrid checkbox column

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding, datagrid

Hi I have a WPF application, with a WPF datagrid with an observable collection of objects. Each object in the observable collection has a boolean variable that is represented by the check box in the data grid. What I am trying to do is make it so that when I check the box and make it "true" for one object of the collection, it makes the other objects of the collection be set to "false". In other words, when I click my data grid checkbox for one object, it unchecks the check box for the other objects in the collection. Its such a simple concept, but I have tried several ways to do this including using a property, but I get stack overflow cause it keeps looping through the collection forever, I tried using an event related to the clicking of the checkbox but I could not get the event to make all other objects in the data grid to be set to false because I couldn't figure out how to access the items in the datagrid to modify them. There must be a really easy way to do this that I am overlooking.

the WPF code it here:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfThings}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,124">

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column with a checkbox" Binding= "{Binding CheckBoxBooleanValue}" />

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I have the c# code:

The collection contains objects from this simple class:

```
public class Thing
{
public bool CheckBoxBooleanValue {get; set;}
}
```

My main Window constructor in my WPF form creates the collection when the application starts:

```
public MainWindow()
{
ObservableCollection<Thing> CollectionOfThings;
Thing thing1 = new Thing();
CollectionOfThings.Add(thing1);
Thing thing2 = new Thing();
CollectionOfThings.Add(thing2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a Radio button functionality. If you have radio buttons that follow the same group, then when you set one to true, others will be set to false. Unfortunately, you can't add a radio button column in your data grid in a straight forward manner. A small trick will do the job for you and I'm pasting the code for that.

NOTE: When I set the group name to "myGroup", this ensures that all radio buttons follow the same group and your desired functionality is met.

```
 <DataGrid Name="data" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfThings}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,124">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton IsChecked= "{Binding CheckBoxBooleanValue}" GroupName="myGroup" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much! I completely forgot about using the radiobutton control!